# function with two complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, analyticity

I have a project regarding analyticity of functions with two complex variables. My question is, what would be some interesting/special functions in $\mathbb C^2$? Maybe something like the complex gamma function $\Gamma(z)$ but extended to $\mathbb C^2$ (if possible) ?
And where could I find more about it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you find Krantz's book *Function theory of several complex variables*, that's a good place. As replacement you can find [notes](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~ebedford/PapersForM537/WiegerinckKorevaar.pdf) online. I don't know which functions you will find interesting, but I would not skip talking about [Hartogs' phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs%27s_extension_theorem), 2.8.3 in the first link.

Comment: @NDB thank you! I will look into it